# how to combine many small hard disk on cheap vps to a big one

Tags: linux, filesystems, vps, nas

I have 10 cheap VPS, and each has a 200GB SSD. I'm downloading videos every day, My clients use rsync pull these data from every VPS, then delete.

But in this way I have to give vps password to my clients. And with the vps amount growing, pulling data scripts also need to be modified on client side .
I want a more simple way, for example use a software combine my small SSD to a big one , and export only one Ip of my vps. Any suggestion?

I have looked up for minio, but I will lost some storage capacity, I want something like RAID0 will not reduce storage capacity.

Another point is the  solution should use all vps  bandwidth, not only one.

[image]